# Tkinter: Getting an image above buttons in grid layout

Tags: python, layout, user-interface, tkinter

i'm new to tkinter and I was trying to make a GUI where there was an image at the top with an area of 4 buttons underneath that image which would be a method of selecting answers. However with the code I have so far the buttons that I create just seem to stay in the top left corner and will not move under the image at all, does anybody know a solution to this please?

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import PhotoImage

root = Tk()

class Class1(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()

        self.master = master        
        self.question1_UI()

    def question1_UI(self):

        self.master.title("GUI")        

        gif1 = PhotoImage(file = 'Image.gif')

        label1 = Label(image=gif1)
        label1.image = gif1 
        label1.grid(row=1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky=NW)

        questionAButton = Button(self, text='Submit',font=('MS', 8,'bold'))
        questionAButton.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = S)
        questionBButton = Button(self, text='Submit',font=('MS', 8,'bold'))
        questionBButton.grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = S)
        questionCButton = Button(self, text='Submit',font=('MS', 8,'bold'))
        questionCButton.grid(row = 3, column = 3, sticky = S)
        questionDButton = Button(self, text='Submit',font=('MS', 8,'bold'))
        questionDButton.grid(row = 3, column = 4, sticky = S)



def main():


    ex = Class1(root)
    root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(),
    root.winfo_screenheight()))         
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using `self` as the parent of `label1`. Besides, the grid manager starts at row 0:

```
def question1_UI(self):
    # ...
    label1 = Label(self, image=gif1)
    label1.image = gif1 
    label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky=NW)

    questionAButton = Button(self, text='Submit',font=('MS', 8,'bold'))
    questionAButton.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = S)
    questionBButton = Button(self, text='Submit',font=('MS', 8,'bold'))
    questionBButton.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = S)
    questionCButton = Button(self, text='Submit',font=('MS', 8,'bold'))
    questionCButton.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = S)
    questionDButton = Button(self, text='Submit',font=('MS', 8,'bold'))
    questionDButton.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = S)
```